# How to hide unwanted fields in CP register form

Tags: members, fields, register

Is there a simple way to hide unwanted non required extra registration fields in the CP member register form?

Answer (score 2):

Nope - no hooks exist in the new member form I'm afraid. I suppose you could hide them with some jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Anna is right. The view file is "/expressionengine/views/members/register.php". Also, an extension can be developed with the hook cp_js_end by having necessary JQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

I personally hack the view as needed if needed. Not ideal but you gotta do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you get really keen, you could use one of the members-as-entries add-ons and then you can present whatever fields you want using regular channel entry fieldtypes.